# Eclipse do not show output

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-oxygen

I'm making 2D drawing on Eclipse Oxygen, there are no error in my code but why it does not show any output. I mean when I click run there are no progress.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.Arc2D;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;

public class HOUSE1 extends Frame {
    public void paint(Graphics2D g) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        g2d.drawString("HOME SWEET HOME",80,60);
        setBackground(Color.white);

        Arc2D arc1 = new Arc2D.Double(250,50,500,300,225,90,Arc2D.Double.PIE);
        g2d.draw(arc1);
        g2d.setColor(Color.red);
        g2d.fill(arc1);

        Rectangle2D rect = new Rectangle2D.Double(325,300,350,300);
        g2d.draw(rect);
        g2d.setColor(Color.blue);
        g2d.fill(rect);

        Rectangle2D rect1 = new Rectangle2D.Double(325,300,350,300);
        g2d.draw(rect1);
        g2d.setColor(Color.black);
        g2d.fill(rect1);            
    }

    public static void main(String[]args){
        HOUSE1 f = new HOUSE1();
        f.setTitle("HOUSE");
        f.setSize(300,100);         
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to make your frame visible.

Just add :

```
f.setVisible(true);
```

You have to fix your paint method declaration to :

```
@override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    // your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your window is blank because your `paint` method is never called.  Your method

```
public void paint(Graphics2D g)    // DOESN'T WORK
```

needs to be changed to

```
public void paint(Graphics g)    // Correct
```

so that it **overrides** the `paint` method in `Frame`. The graphics system will only call `paint(Graphics)`; if your method called `paint` isn't  overriding the method `paint(Graphics)` in `Frame`, the one in `Frame` gets called instead of yours.

Answer (score 0):

1st: In your main void you need to set your frame (f) to visible --> f.setVisible(true)

2nd: Also you might want to f.pack(); right before you set it to visible to to make sure your components are behaving like expected.

3th: In java we use a capital first letter in class like this "House", fully capital words are used for final's.